# IBM MobileFirst 7.0.0 - FWLSE0099E: An error occurred while invoking procedure ]WebserviceAdapter/HttpRequestFWLSE0100E:

Tags: timeout, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am using IBM MobileFirst 7.0.0.  I am getting following error message when i inovke any procedure.

> [ERROR   ] FWLSE0099E: An error occurred while invoking procedure 
>   [project XYZ]WebserviceAdapter/HttpRequestFWLSE0100E:  parameters:
>   [project XYZ] Http request failed: java.net.SocketTimeoutException:
>   Read timed out FWLSE0101E: Caused by:  [project
>   XYZ]java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed
>   outjava.lang.RuntimeException: Http request failed:
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Any idea...??

Comment: Did you read about socket timeout exception in google?

Comment: Yes, even i tried by increasing time in xml.. still facing the problem.

Comment: <connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>80000</connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>  <socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>80000</socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>

Comment: Where does this happen? in the Eclipse development environment or in a remote server?

Comment: its showing error in eclipse..

Answer (score 0):

So this is happening inside the development environment - MobileFirst Studio, in Eclipse... I can only imagine this will happen if the backend you are attempting to reach using the adapter is, not reachable.

Since you did not provide any other information, such as the host you are attempting to connect to, I advise checking:

1. That the host is reachable
2. That the URI you are using is valid
3. To increase the timeout values
4. To test in a different network (at home or a different work network)